# PowerShell RegEx match all possible matches

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following script which includes some RegEx to capture specific information on this site.

```
$Top40Response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://www.radioinfo.com.au/knowledge/chart'

$Top40Response.Content -match '<td\Wclass="twRank">[\s\S]+artist">([^<]*)'
$matches
```

This is matching the last 'artist'. What I want to do is make this so it will run through and match every artist on this page in order top to bottom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PowerShell's `-match` only returns first match. You have to use `Select-String` with `-AllMatches` parameter or `[regex]::Matches`.

`Select-String`:

```
$Top40Response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://www.radioinfo.com.au/knowledge/chart'

$Top40Response.Content |
    Select-String -Pattern '<td\s+class="artist">(.*?)<\/td>' -AllMatches |
        ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} |
            ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

`[regex]::Matches`:

```
$Top40Response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://www.radioinfo.com.au/knowledge/chart'

$Top40Response.Content |
    ForEach-Object {[regex]::Matches($_, '<td\s+class="artist">(.*?)<\/td>')} |
        ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].value}
```

Comment: Great, I like the use of the select-string and the -AllMatches option